# Why is C++ slower than C when doing literaly nothing

Tags: c++, c, performance

C++ is almost 4 times slower than C at doing nothing (at least on my machine). When the following file is compiled by g++, it is 4 times slower than with gcc:

```c
int main() {}
```

With `time sh -c 'for i in $(seq 0 1000) ; do ./a.out ; done'`, I get 0.515s for the C version, and 2s for the C++ one. Why is that?

There isn't a single thing done in this program, and the disassembled program is basically the same in both versions, so why is the C++ version roughly 4 times slower?

My guess is that the C++ library takes a longer time to load, but the assembly is so similar that I can't think of a reason for C++ to be so much slower.

Edit : Well, it appears that I only partially disassembled the program (`objdump -d` instead of `objdump -D`), resulting in me not seeing the library being loaded. It is pretty obvious now seeing the disassembled output that the C++ version just takes longer to load its libraries. What I first meant by "slightly differing" was that the addresses used in `mov` or `call` diverged without calling other functions (if I understand correctly the meaning of `objdump`'s output).

So the main question is solved, but 2 seconds is huge for a program that does nothing. I'm on a x86_64 processor if that helps, and I built the executable `gcc empty.c` and `g++ empty.cpp`. I think the issue really is me using a HDD, thus taking more time to load `libstd++`. I also built with the `-static` flag, and am now getting very similar results (0.246s and 0.241s). The C binary is also exactly the same as the C++ one (if that's not a `diff` bug).

Comment: I somehow doubt that the architects of C++ have spent a lot of time optimizing for the "program that does literally nothing" use-case :)

Comment: "and the disassembled program is basically the same in both versions" basically or exactly or not actually? There's obviously a significant difference between the two programs.

Comment: You do realize that your C++ program has to load an entire C++ library that has many objects that must be initialized, fully, before `main()` gets called? And none of this happens with a C program?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine with GCC 11.2.0 using `gcc empty.c` and `g++ empty.cpp` (no significant difference >5%). Please tell us how do you build the program and the target platform.

Comment: @harold Well, it's 2 seconds to run an empty program 1,000 times, right?

Comment: Try "[ltrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ltrace) ./a.out"

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The time to create the process is certainly far bigger than that: on my machine, it takes 170 us to execute the program once while creating a process is generally as fast as that. The command `sleep 0` takes 130 us per call and `cat /dev/null` 110 us. All of this is reasonable to me.

Comment: I expect the time to be spent in the *dynamic linking* of the C++ program since the C++ library is bigger than the C one. This happens if `iostream` or other similar files are implicitly included for example. You can check that using `perf record` and `perf report` (you need to have sufficient rights by setting 0 in `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid`). For example, on my machine, I can see >90% of the time is spent in the kernel with the empty C program while 70% of the time in the linker for the empty C++ program with `iostream` included with the rest in the kernel (3x slower overall).

Comment: " 0.515s for the C version, and 2s for the C++ one." --perhaps some heavy virus checking?

Comment: Can you try to compile your program with `-static` at the end of the command and check the performance? For example: `g++ empty.cpp -static`.

Comment: @NathanPierson "*it's 2 seconds to run an empty program 1,000 times*" It's actually 2 secs to *launch* a prog from the shell, then run it. And the C++ run part time is probably very similar to the C one.

Comment: Is this yet another "halp halp I'm benchmarking with optimizations off, it's oh-so-strange" question? What happens if you compare _relevant_ builds: `gcc empty.c -O3` and `g++ empty.cpp -O3`? C++ _is_ slower than C if it needs to initialize objects at start-up, because the initialization rules in C++ are far more complex than C, including default constructor calls etc launched by the CRT before calling main(). But there's no obvious reason why it would be a lot slower for an empty program with no variables.

Comment: @Eolien55 Are you benchmarking with optimizations off or not?

Comment: @Lundin as stated in the post, no

Comment: Then that's the root of all your problems, simple as that. Any discussion about performance is senseless until you do.

Comment: @Lundin This is generally true but not here. The code of the program is only few instructions (it should take about few nanosecond). The code of the libc/libstdc++ is already compiled and the header/footer of gcc are precompiled assembly that do not care about optimization flags. You can test and observe yourself that this does not impact the runtime. The OP does not measure the execution time of the program but overheads of the system (eg. process creation, link, sync, etc.) as pointed out by ValeryS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) initial startup is heavier than the C runtime.

[C++ ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) needs to initialize some structures for basic language features. Mutex locks for [thread-safe initialization of data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), [exeptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions), [thread local storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration), [RTTI](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types), etc.

This is why an empty executable created with a C++ compiler will start slower than an empty C program. Likewise, an empty program created with Assembly language will start much faster then a similar program created with C with a full-featured C runtime (CRT, GNU LIBC, etc).

Comment: I do not think the huge overhead of the OP comes from the initialization of the C++ library. It takes less than 1 us (<1%) on my machine to call all the libstdc++ functions combined while the OP pointed out that its C++ program takes *2 seconds* for 1000 calls (ie. 2 ms which is 2000 times bigger than that) !

Comment: @JérômeRichard And if you have a fast SSD and the OP has a slow spinning disk?  And if the OP has made sure all page caches are purged before timing, and you're running over and over with a hot cache holding the exact pages needed?

Comment: @AndrewHenle AFAIK, the C++ library initialization does not access to the storage device (only the linker does in this case). A syscall tracing proves this is not the case with the libstdc++ 6.0.29. Moreover, the latency  of my SSD is significantly bigger than 1 us. Additionally, the OP explicitly provided the command used to measure the timings (I used the same) and there is no explicit page purging done (why it would be different with the glibc btw?). Finally, even if the HDD could be slow, the OS should put the files in the memory cache anyway (especially with many repeated accesses).

Comment: @JérômeRichard *A syscall tracing proves this is not the case with the libstdc++ 6.0.29* Just what do you think calls like this are doing: `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\`\341\t\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1956992, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9a9145b000
mmap(NULL, 1972224, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9a91279000
mprotect(0x7f9a9130f000, 1290240, PROT_NONE) = 0`

Comment: (cont) `mmap(0x7f9a9130f000, 987136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x96000) = 0x7f9a9130f000
mmap(0x7f9a91400000, 299008, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x187000) = 0x7f9a91400000
mmap(0x7f9a9144a000, 57344, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1d0000) = 0x7f9a9144a000
mmap(0x7f9a91458000, 10240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9a91458000`  If that's not "access[ing] ... the storage device", what is it doing?

Comment: (cont) If you're talking about the empty case, then yes, there's no `libstdc++` being linked in, but there's still `libc`, probably `libm`, and `libgcc_s`, all of which still have to be mapped into the process address space, and potentially brought in from actual storage.

Comment: @AndrewHenle AFAIK the syscalls you are showing are coming *from the linker* and not from the libstdc++ initialization. If you link the C++ library statically, they are removed from the execution (while the initialization should still be present). This is why I asked the OP to compile statically its code and also partially why I think the overhead are coming from the linker (see the above comments).

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Those reads should hit the disk cache. I feel that it is inadequate explanation.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard You can try to write some small test only operating system kernel with C++, and you'll see how much do you need from C++ ABI to simply initialize. Offcause if you don't off exceptions, thread safe data initialization and RTTI with compiller options.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, you compare nothing at all, because your program does nothing at all. What you got is not the **program execution time**, which in your case is null, but the **process execution time**, ie load+run+terminate, which is longer if your program needs more resources.

Some numbers could lead some light on this:

say we have `emptyc` and `emptycpp`, respectively compiled with gcc-10.3 and g++-10.3

On my system:

- `emptyc`:

  - file size: 13232
  - elf dynamic section: 17 entries (1 shared lib)
  - truss syscall report: 48 syscalls including 6 open and 11 mmap
- `emptycpp`

  - file size: 13312
  - elf dynamic section: 20 entries (4 shared libs)
  - truss syscall report: 88 syscalls including 15 open and 29 mmap

**Conclusion**:

A program compiled with g++ needs more resources than the same program compiled with gcc.
A process generating 88 syscalls is probably slower than a process generating 48.